# tsLint enabled in Angular 2 webpack

Tags: angular

Actually i created one project with Angular 2 webpack from 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Now I want to enable tsLint in Visual Studio Code. i already add `tsLint.json` file in my project.

And also installed `codelyzer @2.0.0-beta.4` & `tslint @4.0.0` and also made changes in `setting.json` of VS Code.

but tsLint is still not enabled.

Comment: May be wrong path of tsLint.json in setting.json of VS Code.

Comment: actually i tried to use global `tsLint.json` as well. but its work for other project but not with new created webpack's project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install --save-dev tslint-eslint-rules`

Use this link if the above does not work:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint